# How to pass the drag events to other view

Tags: ios, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

Please check the below image this is how my UI looking a draggable view behind the tab bar.

[image][image]

Here I would like to drag the view even if I drag the tab bar. In other words, I have to detect the tab bar drag event and pass it to the underneath view.

I tried passing all the tab bar touch event to underneath view by overriding

```
func point(inside point: CGPoint, 
      with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool
```

but tab bar's actual behavior (tap detection) stopped working.

Is there any way to differentiate the touch and drag event based on that can we pass it to the required view? if not, can you please someone guide me how to solve this?